# paypal Express checkout using credit card

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I'm new to paypal. Kindly guide to me. Its possible to pay with credit card using paypal express checkout(popup)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, users will have the option to sign in or pay with a credit card.  You'll need to make sure the option "PayPal Account Optional" is enabled in your PayPal account profile, too.

If you set `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole` and `LANDINGPAGE=Billing` in your `SetExpressCheckout` request it will force the full credit card form to display by default.

Note: this only works with `LOCALECODE=us` (or if locale is detected to be `us`)

Comment: But does this work if the user is already logged in to paypal? I'm finding that in this case Paypal forces you to use your balance unless the balance is not enough to fulfill the transaction

Comment: If the user is already logged in then that is a separate flow from Guest Checkout, which is what this is explaining.  If they're logged in paying with the PayPal Wallet then it would use the regular hierarchy of payment methods added to that PayPal account.

Comment: Sorry but there's no mention that this is only talking about Guest Checkout... I've found that if user is logged in to paypal, there's no way to force paypal to show the credit card options. Instead, it appears that paypal looks at the current balance and only when that's not enough it presents credit card options

Comment: There should be a little link that says "Change payment method" during checkout when it shows that the funding source is going to be PayPal Balance.