# PayPal Express - How to integrate Card payments?

Tags: c#, paypal

**Question background:**

I've been developing with the PayPal C# API and have implemented an 'Express Checkout' solution. This works perfectly but I can only pay with a PayPal account. I of course want the ability to also pay with Cards.

**Code:**

Parameters set as part of my request to the API:

```
        encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
        encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
        encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
        encoder["BRANDNAME"] = "Test App";
        encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = "120.00";
        encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = "120.00";
        encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
        encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "USD";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1"] = "test1";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1"] = "20.00";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1"] = "1";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2"] = "test2";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2"] = "20.00";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2"] = "2";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME3"] = "test3";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT3"] = "20.00";
        encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY3"] = "3";
```

**Current Implementation:**

Users are taken to PayPal to pay through their account then returned to my site:

[image]

**What I require:**

I need the user to be able to pay both through their account or with a card if they do not have a PayPal account, then be returned to my site. **Is this possible through the Express checkout? If so then how do I implement it?:**

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776744/3864867.  Also, is this a new integration you're working on?  If so, I'd highly suggest checking out the [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) that is built on the PayPal REST API.  It currently supports everything you can do with ExpressCheckout and there's better samples available to show you how to get it all setup and working. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure "PayPal Account Optional" is enabled in your PayPal account profile under Website Payment Preferences.

Then in your SetExpressCheckoutRequest you need to include the following parameters:

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Then you also need to make sure you have the API version updated to at least 109.0.  That should give you what you're after.